# Installed but unable to import pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pip, pymongo

I have installed pymongo using pip3 on terminal and through Jupyter notebook. However, it shows the following error when I try to import it, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'".

(OS is MAC)

The error screenshot
[image: error]

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: It looks like jupyter is configured to use a different version of python, where that module has not been installed.  Show us the output of this code: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: This is the output ['/Users/shivanisingh/Downloads/mongo_flask_resources', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '', '/Users/shivanisingh/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  `pip3` is using `/Users/shivanisingh/miniconda`, but jupyter is using `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!
I wanted to ask, how should I install pymongo then, I tried with pip and from source

Comment: I deactivated conda and installed using pip again, it is working now, thanks!

Comment: I suspect if you used current best-practices inside Jupyter, the installation may have work in Jupyter without needing to jump through those hoops. Not 100% sure though. You probably could test it by installing something else. Anyway, you'll have a much better experience going forward if you use the `%pip install` when trying to install from inside a Jupyter `.ipynb` file. The modern magic command was added in the last few years to insure the installation occurs in the environment being used by the kernel backing the running notebook. (There is a `%conda install` equivalent for use from ...

Comment: <continued> inside notebooks, too.) See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands. The use of the the exclamation point for install can lead to issues, which may explain what you were seeing. See the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about why that may be the case and consider anything saying to use an exclamation point in an install step as outdated.